# Simulating a click on GearVR

Tags: java, android, view, webview

I am trying to simulate a click on GearVR inside a webview.
Since the content in webview can be any website, it is not under a *controlled environment*, I need the user to *click* on the headset, get the X and Y position in the webview and simulate a click.
I've tried the `MotionEvent.obtain`, but it needs the x and y positions first to simulate a click, and I don't have, since it is not a real touch.

Any ideas?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Thanks tmthydvnprt.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around to see if I can get absolute coordinates from MotionEvent but i don't think that's possible [1].

However, you can get the X and Y position of what the user is currently looking at by performing a ray trace (depending on how you've implemented your application), and then correlate the hit point as a result of that trace to your web view to infer a "click". Hope this helps!

https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/issues/231

Answer (score 0):

Yes to add to @DarkTemplar's response, cast a ray from your virtual position in the direction of your looking direction. Your webview is probably mapped to a quad in space I assume. Then you perform a ray-plane intersection, then check if the intersection point is in the quad. If it is, figure out the relative coordinate of the intersection within the quad and then simulate the click there.

You are encouraged to check out
https://github.com/samsung/gearvrf/wiki
more developers can help you there